# Practical example of how properties are used in objective-c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, properties

I am having a hard time on how to understand the actual use of setting a property to variables and objects. I tried to read many tutorials and apple documentation but still i am not able to understand on why we should use a property and why we need to synthesize the property? Considering we declare

```
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSString *str;
```

why do we need to declare a property. As far as i understand, we can access string object `str` through out your class. But why do we need to create a property here?

Can someone please help me out?

Comment: Probably a duplicate and may get closed. It's unfortunate though because I don't think enough can be said on this simple, yet difficult to understand topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Properties are usually used to access instance variables from outside of the class.

For example, if you have a pointer to your class you can get/set the property like this

```
someObject.str = @"some string";
```

You also have to `@synthesize` the property, usually like this:

```
@synthesize str = _str;
```

In that snippet, `_str` is the instance variable that the property sets and gets.

The properties are essentially just shortcuts for creating accessors (setters/getters).

For example, a setter using your property would look something like this:

```
- (void)setStr:(NSString *)str {
    if(str != _str) {
        [_str release];
        _str = [str retain];
    }
}
```

and the getter would look something like this:

```
- (NSString *)str {
    return _str;
}
```

By creating properties, the previous two code blocks are automatically created for you.

Comment: Note that for retain setters, you should check if the new value is not equal to the old one before releasing the old one. Otherwise it might be too late to retain it afterwards :D

Comment: We should never be accessing _str in code, unless we are retaining/releasing it. Right? In rest of the cases we should access _str only through the property str. Is that so.

Comment: If you're using the standard getter, I don't think there's any reason why you shouldn't be able to use `_str` directly. Though it's usually good practice to access it through the property anyway for consistency.

Answer (score 1):

Properties are a public interface that enables **other** objects to inspect and set the value of a variable inside the object where the variable was declared.

You could achieve the same thing by writing explicit methods that get and set the value of a variable.

Note that when you get right down to it, the property/synthesize pair in Objective-C is actually short hand for the compiler to build those methods for you using a well defined pattern.

Thus in objective-c

```
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSString *str;
....
synthesize str;
...
```

Ends up creating two methods defined as:

```
void setStr:(NSString*) value;
NSString* str;
```

And that writing

```
Object.str = @"Hello world";
NSString* value = Object.str;
```

Get converted respectively into:

```
[Object setStr:@"Hello world"];
NSString* value = [Object str];
```

Answer (score 1):

The use of properties is a facility that Obj-C offers to programmers.

You can write a program with or without properties.

You can use properties in combination with the `@synthesize` compiler directive.

A property declaration instructs the compiler to declare a getter/setter pair of methods.
You must manually code the setter and the getter. This property declaration allows you to use dot notation to access the instance variables. The compiler will translate the dot notation to the appropiate getter/setter method.

You can use the `@synthesize` directive to tell the compiler to generate the code for the getter/setter methods.

Using properties, you have to write less code and you can use dot notation.
The other way, not using properties, you have to write the getter/setter methods and the dot notation is not allowed.

But you can write a program either way. So, it is up to you to use properties and synthesize them.